# php e-commerce cart update pdo

Tags: php, pdo, e-commerce

I'm a php newbie. Increase quantity button doesn't work. I'm trying to do this without ajax.
Thanks

cart file:
...
&key_cartitem_increase=ok">+

....

pdo file:

```
    if (isset($_GET['key_cartitem_increase'])) {
    if($_GET['key_cartitem_increase']=="ok"){
         
        $cart_id=$_GET['tblcart_id'];

        $increaseitem=$db->prepare("UPDATE tbl_cart SET         
                        tblcart_userid=:tblcart_userid,                     
                        tblcart_productid=:tblcart_productid,   
                        tblcart_quantity=:tblcart_quantity+1                    
                        WHERE tblcart_id=id");

        $kontrol=$increaseitem->execute(array(
            'id' => $_GET['tblcart_id'],
            'tblcart_userid' => $_GET['tblcart_userid'],
            'tblcart_productid' => $_GET['tblcart_productid'],
            'tblcart_quantity' => $_GET['tblcart_quantity']
            ));

        if($kontrol){
            Header("Location:../../front-cart.php?status=ok");

        }else{
            Header("Location:../../front-cart.php?status=no");
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can do the increment in two methode :

First with you GET param, when you bind the tblcart_quantity to add +1 to this value **'tblcart_quantity' => intval($_GET['tblcart_quantity']) + 1** :

```php
 if (isset($_GET['key_cartitem_increase'])) {
    if($_GET['key_cartitem_increase']=="ok"){
         
        $cart_id=$_GET['tblcart_id'];

        $increaseitem=$db->prepare("UPDATE tbl_cart SET         
                        tblcart_userid=:tblcart_userid,                     
                        tblcart_productid=:tblcart_productid,   
                        tblcart_quantity=:tblcart_quantity                    
                        WHERE tblcart_id=id");

        $kontrol=$increaseitem->execute(array(
            'id' => $_GET['tblcart_id'],
            'tblcart_userid' => $_GET['tblcart_userid'],
            'tblcart_productid' => $_GET['tblcart_productid'],
            'tblcart_quantity' => intval($_GET['tblcart_quantity']) + 1
            ));

        if($kontrol){
            Header("Location:../../front-cart.php?status=ok");

        }else{
            Header("Location:../../front-cart.php?status=no");
        }
    }
```

Second method let's MySQL do the increment of one, to don this just edit the update request to edit this  **tblcart_quantity=tblcart_quantity+1**  :

```php
 if (isset($_GET['key_cartitem_increase'])) {
    if($_GET['key_cartitem_increase']=="ok"){
         
        $cart_id=$_GET['tblcart_id'];

        $increaseitem=$db->prepare("UPDATE tbl_cart SET         
                        tblcart_userid=:tblcart_userid,                     
                        tblcart_productid=:tblcart_productid,   
                        tblcart_quantity=tblcart_quantity+1                    
                        WHERE tblcart_id=id");

        $kontrol=$increaseitem->execute(array(
            'id' => $_GET['tblcart_id'],
            'tblcart_userid' => $_GET['tblcart_userid'],
            'tblcart_productid' => $_GET['tblcart_productid'],
            'tblcart_quantity' => $_GET['tblcart_quantity']
            ));

        if($kontrol){
            Header("Location:../../front-cart.php?status=ok");

        }else{
            Header("Location:../../front-cart.php?status=no");
        }
    }
```